# PL SQL Object invalid error - can't find the source

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a sample database and I need to write a stored procedure to print a given recipe (which the db contains, including ingredients and amount - so I need to JOIN tables)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_printrecipe (RecipeName IN Recipe.RecipeTitle%TYPE)
IS
  TYPE rec_printrecipe IS RECORD
  (
    rec_IngName Ingredients.IngredientName%TYPE, 
    rec_Amount Recipe_Ingredients.Amount%TYPE,
    rec_MeasureDesc Measurements.MeasurementDescription%TYPE,
  )
  CURSOR cur_printrecipe IS
    SELECT i.ingredientName, ri.Amount, m.MeasurementDescription FROM Recipes r
    JOIN Recipe_Ingredients ri ON r.RecipeID = ri.RecipeID
    JOIN Ingredients i ON ri.IngredientID = i.IngredientID
    JOIN Measurements m ON ri.MeasureAmountID = m.MeasurementDescription
    WHERE r.RecipeTitle = RecipeName;
BEGIN
  IF NOT cur_printrecipe%ISOPEN THEN
    OPEN cur_printrecipe;
  END IF;

  LOOP
    FETCH cur_printrecipe INTO rec_printrecipe;
    EXIT WHEN cur_printrecipe%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line( rec_Amount || ' ' 
                          rec_MeasureDesc || ' of '
                          rec_IngName
                        );
  END LOOP;
END;
/

-- CALLING THE STORED PROCEDURE
DECLARE 
 recipe recipes.RecipeTitle%TYPE := 'Irish Stew';
BEGIN
  proc_printrecipe(recipe);
END;
```

But the Script Output (working with **Oracle SQL Developer 1.1.3**) gives me:
Warning: execution completed with warning

```
PROCEDURE proc_printrecipe Compiled.

Error starting at line 33 in command:
DECLARE 
 recipe recipes.RecipeTitle%TYPE := 'Irish Stew';
BEGIN
  proc_printrecipe(recipe);
END; 
Error report:
ORA-06550: Line 4, Column 3:
PLS-00905: Object COOK.PROC_PRINTRECIPE is invalid
ORA-06550: Line 4, Column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't forget to close the cursor you open before you exit the procedure. Otherwise at some point in the future your code will take out the database with an out of memory situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `show errors` after the procedure compilation to see the problem, at least in SQL*Plus and SQL Developer; or query the `user_errors` view:

```
select * from user_errors
where type = 'PROCEDURE'
and name = 'PROC_PRINTRECIPE';
```

But some obvious errors are that you have an extra comma at the end of your record declaration; you are missing a semicolon; and you need to declare an instance of that type:

```
  TYPE rec_printrecipe_type IS RECORD
  (
    IngName Ingredients.IngredientName%TYPE, 
    Amount Recipe_Ingredients.Amount%TYPE,
    MeasureDesc Measurements.MeasurementDescription%TYPE
  );
  rec_printrecipe rec_printrecipe_type;
```

Your cursor-open check is redundant as it can't be open at that point; but you should be closing it explicitly at the end of the procedure.

And your `dbms_output` call is referring to fields directly without specifying the record they are part of, and has incomplete concatenation; so you'd need to do:

```
    dbms_output.put_line( rec_printrecipe.Amount || ' ' ||
                          rec_printrecipe.MeasureDesc || ' of ' ||
                          rec_printrecipe.IngName
                        );
```

You're assuming whoever calls this will be able to see the `dbms_output` buffer. Hopefully you're already doing `set serveroutput on`.

There may still be other problems that `user_errors` will reveal.

SQL Developer is up to version 4 now, so you might to think about upgrading. Codo's answer might refer to something more modern than version 1.1.3, for example.

Comment: The error output helps a lot! thank you.. and I have removed the other errors, you found. still not working. Its a pity, that I have the error messages in a mix of german and english here..

Comment: ok.. apparently the errors lay in these three lines
    FETCH cur_printrecipe INTO rec_printrecipe;
    EXIT WHEN cur_printrecipe%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line( rec_printrecipe.Amount || ' ' ||

It says that the **rec_printrecipe** can't be used on the left side of a delcaration.. 
It says twice "Statement ignored"..
and the cur_printrecipe%NOTFOUND doesn't seem to work either..

Comment: @apoc - you need a variable to select into, which is an instance of your type. You can't work with a type directly. Updated the answer - note some name changes...

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that your stored procedure is invalid, i.e. it hasn't successfully compiled due to errors in the code.

- In the *Connections* view of SQL Developer, expand your connection.
- Expand the item *Procedures*.
- Click on *PROC_PRINTRECIPE*
- In the view that opens, click on the *Compile* button.

SQL Developer will then show where the errors in your procedures are.

Comment: I'm not able to find a Compile button there. But I get the error messages, with the select statement Alex Poole gave me.